# Detecting IDs from unique identifier in the image

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am researching a way to detect a person with a specific ID (on the calling application database) from reading contents of the image (i.e. what that person is wearing) using opencv or deep learning.

Suppose you have a calling application with a database of registered people that regularly visit a store. Suppose those people are wearing a logo with a unique visual identifier (like a barcode but not a barcode) and our system wants to match them with their associated ID on the system.

The immediate solution that comes to mind is just to train a CNN to look for that unique identifier - which is fine if you have to classify 10 or even 20 people, but what if you have 100+ people with unique visual cues. Obviously training a network on each image would not scale.

I wonder if there's an opencv implementation of this without deep learning perhaps as this would make it much faster at runtime

Comment: _"Suppose those people are wearing a logo with a unique visual identifier"_ than just detect the logo and decode the identifier, pretty much like an [aurco marker](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html) for example

Answer (score 0):

This problem is re-identification. One of the ways for - Siamese Networks. They are trained to produce vectors in multidimensional space, which are located far from each other for different objects and close for similar objects.
You can see [decision from OpenVINO](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/R5/_docs_Retail_object_reidentification_pedestrian_rmnet_based_0076_caffe_desc_person_reidentification_retail_0076.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need deep learning on this one, what you have is clear, you will have features in the image and need to track those on the video.

Check on Feature Detectors, some good ones are:

- [FAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_from_accelerated_segment_test)
- [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features)
- [ORB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_FAST_and_rotated_BRIEF)

If you check this image:
[image]
You see that we can match the image of the book to any image, and therefore we could eventually track it (which is done in things like SLAM (Simultaneous Localization And Mapping) or SFM (Structure From Motion))

Since you care about the solution scaling up, generating the features would be the difficult part, some libraries that have done a good job there are [ARUCO](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html) where you create dictionaries of tags that are easily distinguishable and detected:

[image] 
[image]

Also there are [April Tags](https://april.eecs.umich.edu/wiki/AprilTags), Alvar tags and so on, each one having it's own advantages and disadvantages (Also the feature detectors have difference licensing models).
You could also create you own tags or features to detect.

I hope this is a good starting point!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) might be a good fit for this?